# selecting a radio button in a radio group causes select some radio button in different radio groups

Tags: android, radiobuttonlist

i am writing a quiz app in android devices that there are some questions in that. Each question has a radio group and at least 4 answer options by radio buttons.

for quiz page that is the quiz activity, i used i a list view.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/content_question_list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="ir.testravanshenasi.segalclinic.test.QuestionListActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_question_list">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <TextView
        android:text="test questions"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/activity_question_list_list"
        android:layout_height="430dp">


    </ListView>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">

        <Button
            android:text="cancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/activity_question_list_cancel"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:onClick="onCancelBtnClick" />

        <Button
            android:text="end"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/activity_question_list_complete"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            android:onClick="onCompleteBtnClick" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and I made a layout for each question row.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">

    <TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/question_id"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/question_text" />

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/question_options">

    <RadioButton
        android:text="RadioButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/question_option_1"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <RadioButton
        android:text="RadioButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/question_option_2"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <RadioButton
        android:text="RadioButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/question_option_3"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <RadioButton
        android:text="RadioButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/question_option_4"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <RadioButton
        android:text="RadioButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/question_option_5"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

and i add questions as SimpleAdapter to list view.

```
        String[] from = {"qid" , "question" , "op1","op2" , "op3" , "op4"};

        int[] to = { R.id.question_id , R.id.question_text , R.id.question_option_1 ,R.id.question_option_2 , R.id.question_option_3 , R.id.question_option_4 };

        questionsList = parse(jsonArray);

        SimpleAdapter rlt = new SimpleAdapter(
                getBaseContext() , questionsList , R.layout.question ,from , to );

        lv.setAdapter(rlt);
```

The problem is that when i select (for example) the first answer option in a question , in some other questions the first option selected too.

I test my app at Genymotion.

thank you.

Comment: show the code you are implementig

Comment: no one will be able to help you until you show them what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem and that is my solution :

I made a class that entends SimpelAdapter and used it here.I hava a list that store the question id and the choosed radio button number. When a radio button is choosed , i store its number in the list and in each cycle of list i test whether the radiobuttons number exists in the list or not? and i choose radio group method for checking or clear the check for radio buttons.

```
 public class row_question_list extends SimpleAdapter {

List<HashMap<String , Object>> questionsList;

public row_question_list(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, data, resource, from, to);
    questionsList = (List<HashMap<String , Object>>) data;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    RadioButton op1 = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.question_option_1);
    RadioButton op2 = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.question_option_2);
    RadioButton op3 = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.question_option_3);
    RadioButton op4 = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.question_option_4);
    RadioButton op5 = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.question_option_5);
    final RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) v.findViewById(R.id.question_options);


    op1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            questionsList.get(position).put("answer","1");
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    op2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            questionsList.get(position).put("answer","2");
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    op3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            questionsList.get(position).put("answer","3");
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    op4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            questionsList.get(position).put("answer","4");
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    op5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            questionsList.get(position).put("answer","5");
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });


    if(questionsList.get(position).get("answer").toString().matches("0")){
        rg.clearCheck();
        rg.refreshDrawableState();

    } else if(questionsList.get(position).get("answer").toString().matches("1")){
        rg.check(R.id.question_option_1);
        rg.refreshDrawableState();

    }else if(questionsList.get(position).get("answer").toString().matches("2")){
        rg.check(R.id.question_option_2);
        rg.refreshDrawableState();

    }else if(questionsList.get(position).get("answer").toString().matches("3")){
        rg.check(R.id.question_option_3);
        rg.refreshDrawableState();

    }else if(questionsList.get(position).get("answer").toString().matches("4")){
        rg.check(R.id.question_option_4);
        rg.refreshDrawableState();

    }else if(questionsList.get(position).get("answer").toString().matches("5")){
        rg.check(R.id.question_option_5);
        rg.refreshDrawableState();

    }

    return v;
}
```

}

and i used this class in making the list items :

```
        String[] from = {"question" , "op1","op2" , "op3" , "op4"};

        int[] to = { R.id.question_text , R.id.question_option_1 ,R.id.question_option_2 , R.id.question_option_3 , R.id.question_option_4 };

        questionsList = parse(jsonArray);

        row_question_list rql = new row_question_list(
                getBaseContext() , questionsList , R.layout.question , from , to
        );

        lv.setAdapter(rql);
```